# Rails Helper to display rating in stars

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using Rails 6. Here's a piece that I wrote just to display number of stars. Obviously I am disgusted by my own code. How would you refactor?

```
# application_helper.rb
module ApplicationHelper
  def show_star_rating(rating)
    zero_star_icon_name = "star"
    full_star_icon_name = "star_fill"
    half_star_icon_name = "star_lefthalf_fill"
    total_stars = []
    round_by_half = (rating * 2).round / 2.0
    (round_by_half.to_i).times { total_stars << full_star_icon_name }

    if round_by_half - round_by_half.to_i == 0.5
      total_stars << half_star_icon_name
    end

    if total_stars.size != 5
      (5 - total_stars.size).times { total_stars << zero_star_icon_name }
    end

    total_stars
  end
end

# show.html.erb
<% show_star_rating(agent_review.rating).each do |star| %>
  <i class="f7-icons"><%= star %></i>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Refactoring advice typically belongs on the code review stack exchange.

Comment: I did request in Code Review, but got no reply.

Comment: @Victor Wow, 8 views in 2 days. The ruby tag looks, err, abandoned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of the [`Array.new`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-c-new), passing in the maximum number of stars you want to show, and defaulting all the stars to empty. Then, you can [`fill`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-fill) in the number of full stars you need. Then, finally, thanks to `Numeric`'s [`divmod`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Numeric.html#method-i-divmod) returning either `0` or `1` for the number of half stars you need, you make one more pass and `fill` in the number of half stars you need:

```
module StarHelper
  EMPTY_STAR_ICON = 'star'.freeze
  FULL_STAR_ICON = 'star_fill'.freeze
  HALF_STAR_ICON = 'star_lefthalf_fill'.freeze

  def full_and_half_star_count(rating)
    (rating * 2).round.divmod(2)
  end

  def stars(rating, max_stars: 5)
    full_stars, half_stars = full_and_half_star_count(rating)

    Array.new(max_stars, EMPTY_STAR_ICON).
      fill(FULL_STAR_ICON, 0, full_stars).
      fill(HALF_STAR_ICON, full_stars, half_stars)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I'd move the `full_and_half_star_count` private too.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would implement `show_star_rating`:

```
def show_star_rating(rating)
  zero_star_icon_name = "star"
  full_star_icon_name = "star_fill"
  half_star_icon_name = "star_lefthalf_fill"
  rating_round_point5 = (rating * 2).round / 2.0

  (1..5).map do |i|
    next(full_star_icon_name) if i <= rating_round_point5
    next(half_star_icon_name) if rating_round_point5 + 0.5 == i
    zero_star_icon_name
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. It's generally to keep the HTML code in the view as much as we can though. Makes it easier for front-end developer.

Comment: You don't need the `to_a` on the range. Also, you could replace the if-elsif conditional with a couple of guard clauses using `next(value)`.